# Correct way to catch errors with async/await

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, async-await

I have application where I need to wait for each HTTP response. So the calls need to be executed in specific order and some of them require response of another service. I thought that it will be possible to catch error in one place - root/main method where error will be propagated. But it seems to be not working like that... Is it even possible? Or does it mean that I need to use try/catch block in each method where I'm using `await`?? Let's assume this pseudo code:

#### user.wrapper.service.ts

```
// Class which wraps real UserService with HTTP calls
export class UserWrapperService {
   async getUserById(id: number): Promise<UserResponse> {
      return await this.userService.getUser(id).toPromise() as UserResponse;
   }

   async getUserDetails(userName: string): Promise<UserDetailsResponse> {
      return await this.userService.getUserDetails(userName).toPromise() as UserDetailsResponse;
   } 
}
```

#### main-component.ts

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

   async ngOnInit() {
      try {
         await this.retrieveDetailsForEachUser();
      } catch (e) {
        this.router.navigate(['/error']);
      }
   }

   private async retrieveDetailsForEachUser(): Promise<any> {
      for (let counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
         const user = await this.userWrapperService.getUserById(counter);
         console.log(user);
         const details = await this.userWrapperService.getUserDetails(user.name);
         // use this details in another service with bigger method, where is present more async/await
      }
   }
}
```

I was hoping that if something will go wrong in methods of `UserWrapperService` the error will be propagated and catched in `MainComponent`. Or at least that it is somehow possible to achieve. But it seems that I need to throw exception and try/catch to all `async` methods which are `await`ing for something. Am I right? Is there any prettier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Hmm, I would expect this to work fine. I've used the same pattern before successfully. The key is to make sure you are using `await` within the `try` block, which you are.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `try-catch` block when using **async-await** to handle errors and you are doing it correctly. The only thing which seems wrong to me is that you are awaiting in the service method while returning the result of async call, which will return you a `Promise<Promise<UserResponse>`, which is not the expected behavior.

Modify your code to remove the `await` keyword in service class as below and await only in the component class.

**user.wrapper.service.ts**

```
export class UserWrapperService {
   async getUserById(id: number): Promise<UserResponse> {
      return this.userService.getUser(id).toPromise();
   }

   async getUserDetails(userName: string): Promise<UserDetailsResponse> {
      return this.userService.getUserDetails(userName).toPromise();
   } 
}
```

Now you will be able to catch errors, handle them and navigate to error page as required in the main-component class.

Comment: Thanks for answer. You could be right about that, but I have one more question. Does it mean that I need to use `try-catch` block in each place where I really need to await for response? I'm talking about my commented line in the code. I have multiple services, which implements one interface, where I also need to execute sequence of calls, which are using response of previous call.

Comment: @Lui try-catch block is not necessary when using the **async-await** approach. If you don't use them, the execution of the method stops abruptly, i.e., anything below the await call does not execute. The error message will also be logged in the console along with the stacktrace. But it is a good practice to wrap the await calls with try-catch so that you can handle the errors and execute some logic related to failure case, like performing cleanups and release resources that are not needed, if any.

Comment: I'm aware that `try-catch` is not required, but I think that in my case it is, right? Because, no matter what, if something goes wrong, I would like to redirect to `error` page. And currently I see the stacktrace in console as you mentioned and nothing below await is not executed. But at the same time, user has no idea that something went wrong and I need to redirect him.

Comment: In that case you need to add the try-catch block to show some error content that is relevant for the user in case of an Error.